# SQLSERVER - Import and parsing special XML coming from wordpress

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-parsing

I have written a script that loads an xml file and parse it.

This is the script and a partial xml file as example:

## SQL SCRIPT

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML
DECLARE @hDoc AS INT

CREATE TABLE #XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\temp\wordpress.2017-05-22.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM #XMLwithOpenXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT *
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'rss/channel/item')
WITH 
    (       
        Product [VARCHAR](50) 'title',
        Category [VARCHAR](50) 'category'
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

DROP TABLE #XMLwithOpenXML
```

## XML FILE ( Partial )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>Bancone Tetris</title>
        <category domain="categorie-prodotti" nicename="arredi-light"><![CDATA[Arredi light]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-outlet" nicename="arredi-light"><![CDATA[arredi light]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-prodotti" nicename="banconi"><![CDATA[Banconi]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-outlet" nicename="banconi"><![CDATA[Banconi]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-outlet" nicename="luci"><![CDATA[luci]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[wpcf-codice]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[cod.05-008]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[wpcf-size]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[145x80xh110 cm]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
</item>
<item>
... SAME STRUCTURE AS ABOVE
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

The problem I faced

1. I need to list all **products** with all the related **category**, in this moment the script returns all the products with **only the first category**.
2. I don't know how to return all the postmeta ( key , value ) list for each product...

Hope its clear, 
thanks to support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am rusty with OPENXML but you don't need it for this. Let's start with some updated sample data:

```
INSERT INTO #XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<rss version="2.0"
    xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/"
    xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
    xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
    xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
    xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"
>
<channel>
    <item>
        <title>Bancone Tetris</title>
        <category domain="categorie-prodotti" nicename="arredi-light"><![CDATA[Arredi light]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-outlet" nicename="arredi-light"><![CDATA[arredi light]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-prodotti" nicename="banconi"><![CDATA[Banconi]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-outlet" nicename="banconi"><![CDATA[Banconi]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-outlet" nicename="luci"><![CDATA[luci]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[wpcf-codice]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[cod.05-008]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[wpcf-size]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[145x80xh110 cm]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Bancone Tetris Part2</title>
        <category domain="categorie-outlet" nicename="banconi"><![CDATA[Banconi]]></category>
        <category domain="categorie-outlet" nicename="luci"><![CDATA[luci]]></category>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[wpcf-codice]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[cod.05-008]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
        <wp:postmeta>
            <wp:meta_key><![CDATA[wpcf-size]]></wp:meta_key>
            <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[145x80xh110 cm]]></wp:meta_value>
        </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>' AS BulkColumn, GETDATE();
```

This query will get you all products and related categories:

```
SELECT 
  product  = item.value('(title/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  category = category.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)')
FROM #XMLwithOpenXML x
CROSS APPLY x.XMLData.nodes('rss/channel/item') n1(item)
CROSS APPLY item.nodes('category')   n2(category);
```

**Results**

```
product                    category
-------------------------- --------------
Bancone Tetris             Arredi light
Bancone Tetris             arredi light
Bancone Tetris             Banconi
Bancone Tetris             Banconi
Bancone Tetris             luci
Bancone Tetris Part2       Banconi
Bancone Tetris Part2       luci
```

For your wp:postmeta stuff you need to refer to the wp namespace. Here's three ways to do it (note my comments):

```
-- Option #1: USE "*:" for "all namespaces (MY FAVORITE)
SELECT 
  product  = item.value('(title/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  category = category.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  meta_key = postmeta.value('(*:meta_key/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  meta_val = postmeta.value('(*:meta_value/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)')
FROM #XMLwithOpenXML x
CROSS APPLY x.XMLData.nodes('rss/channel/item') n1(item)
CROSS APPLY item.nodes('category')   n2(category)
CROSS APPLY item.nodes('*:postmeta') n3(postmeta);

-- Option #2: USE "WITH XMLNAMESPACES"
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/' as wp) 
SELECT 
  product  = item.value('(title/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  category = category.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  meta_key = postmeta.value('(wp:meta_key/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  meta_val = postmeta.value('(wp:meta_value/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)')
FROM #XMLwithOpenXML x
CROSS APPLY x.XMLData.nodes('rss/channel/item') n1(item)
CROSS APPLY item.nodes('category')   n2(category)
CROSS APPLY item.nodes('wp:postmeta') n3(postmeta);

-- Option #3: Inline Namespace declaration
SELECT 
  product  = item.value('(title/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  category = category.value('(text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  meta_key = postmeta.value('declare namespace wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"; (wp:meta_key/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)'),
  meta_val = postmeta.value('declare namespace wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"; (wp:meta_value/text())[1]', 'varchar(1000)')
FROM #XMLwithOpenXML x
CROSS APPLY x.XMLData.nodes('rss/channel/item') n1(item)
CROSS APPLY item.nodes('category')   n2(category)
CROSS APPLY item.nodes('declare namespace wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/"; wp:postmeta') n3(postmeta);
```

All three solutions return:

```
product              category             meta_key             meta_val
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
Bancone Tetris       Arredi light         wpcf-codice          cod.05-008
Bancone Tetris       Arredi light         wpcf-size            145x80xh110 cm
Bancone Tetris       arredi light         wpcf-codice          cod.05-008
Bancone Tetris       arredi light         wpcf-size            145x80xh110 cm
Bancone Tetris       Banconi              wpcf-codice          cod.05-008
Bancone Tetris       Banconi              wpcf-size            145x80xh110 cm
Bancone Tetris       Banconi              wpcf-codice          cod.05-008
Bancone Tetris       Banconi              wpcf-size            145x80xh110 cm
Bancone Tetris       luci                 wpcf-codice          cod.05-008
Bancone Tetris       luci                 wpcf-size            145x80xh110 cm
Bancone Tetris Part2 Banconi              wpcf-codice          cod.05-008
Bancone Tetris Part2 Banconi              wpcf-size            145x80xh110 cm
Bancone Tetris Part2 luci                 wpcf-codice          cod.05-008
Bancone Tetris Part2 luci                 wpcf-size            145x80xh110 cm
```